# Get instance of iframe after getting event from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I saw lot of post to communicate from iframe. But my question is after that.

I got the event in parent, from iframe, now i want to get instance of iframe so that I can ask jquery to set height based on msg passed from iframe.

In simple words, I am trying to define few common msg to communicate from iframe to parent. One of the message is to change height of it. so that a common method can receive message from 1 or more iframe and change height of them.

Parent code-----

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {

    msgData = $.parseJSON(e.data);

    if(msgData.iframeload){

        if(msgData.iframeload.height){
             $(e.source).css('height',''+msgData.iframeload.height);
        }
    }

},false);
```

iframe code----

```
var msgToParent = {
iframeload : {
          height : window.document.body.scrollHeight
        }
};
parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(msgToParent),"*");
```

My problem is what code i should write to replace

```
$(e.source).css('height',''+msgData.iframeload.height);
```

if I change it with id of iframe then it worked. so i want a way to get object of iframe which can help me to set height.

```
$('#<id of iframe>').css('height',''+msgData.iframeload.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well dirty mind always works... :) This what i did and added a src as extra element in msg from iframe as document.location.href ...

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {

    msgData = $.parseJSON(e.data);

    if(msgData.iframeload){

        if(msgData.iframeload.height){

            $.each($('iframe'),function(i,curIfra){

                if(msgData.src==curIfra.src){
                    $(curIfra).css('height',''+msgData.iframeload.height);
                }
            });
        }
    }

},false);
```